# Concurrent Modification Exception in Array list of users

Tags: java, android

I was done this code to the show each user, who chat with the logged in user. this code gives me an error of ConcurrentModificationException.this happens when I reply to the message.

I used Array lists for store data that are retrieved from the firebase. the error causes in the code line of " for (User user1 : users) { ". How to fix this issue.

```
 private void readChats() {

        users = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                users.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    // Display each user from the chats
                    for (String id : usersList) {
                        if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
                            if (users.size() != 0) {
                                for (User user1 : users) { // getting error
                                    if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId())){
                                        users.add(user);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                users.add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                usersAdapter= new UsersAdapter(getContext(), users);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
```

This giving following error messages.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dasun96.vreyedoctor, PID: 20759
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at com.dasun96.vreyedoctor.ChatsFragment$2.onDataChange(ChatsFragment.java:93)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
```

Comment: Iterate over copy instead of original arraylist

Comment: I do not have any idea about android, but if possible use CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of using ArrayList.

Comment: `users.add(user);`. You can't add to a list that you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try `users = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();` instead of `users = new ArrayList<>();`?

`ArrayLists` are fail-fast, meaning they will throw out an exception when you try to do an illegal operation. An example of an illegal operation may be adding/removing from an `ArrayList` while iteration through it (without an iterator).

Long story short, use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and you won't have any more headaches.

Comment: Just a side note, you can also use a standard for loop instead of an enhanced for loop to get rid of the exception. However, you need to keep track of your index variable if you are removing stuff from the middle.